# JHipster-Liquibase: How to upload an Image file blob?

Tags: postgresql, jhipster, liquibase

Given a table with the following columns:

```
<column name="image" type="longblob">
    <constraints nullable="true" />
</column>
<column name="image_content_type" type="varchar(255)">
    <constraints nullable="true" />
</column>
```

How can I upload an Image from file, e.g. MyImage.jpeg? The underlying DB is PostgreSQL.

Comment: probably it is a high-level type used by JHipster/Liquibase

Comment: the actual column type is bytea

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried?

Comment: I did it, I'll answer my own question later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following changeSet does what I was looking for:

```
    <changeSet id="632342634534534e53" author="developer">
    <update schemaName="public"
            tableName="my_table">
        <column name="image" type="longblob" valueBlobFile="../../../images/1.MyImage.jpg"/>
        <column name="image_content_type" type="varchar(255)" value="image/jpeg"/>
        <where>id = 1</where>
    </update>
    </changeSet>
```

Being this the path of the images:

`/src/main/resources/images`

and this the path for the changelog:

```
/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/MyChangelog.xml
```

Comment: How to set the path valueBlobFile? from which location it refers?

Comment: it is relative to the changelog location. E.g. I'm going back 3 levels `valueBlobFile="../../../images/1.MyImage.jpg"`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but in my case the accepted solution didnt work out as long as column type is OID rather than Blob (postgres 12.x)

So I ended up with the solution below, that uses computedValue and postgres' functions to convert a Base64 image to OID.

```
 <insert tableName="IMAGES">
        <column name="image_id" valueSequenceNext="image_id_seq"/> 
        <column name="name" value="some image name"/>
        <column name="content" valueComputed="lo_from_bytea(0, decode('DLxmEfVUC9CAmjiNyVphWw==', 'base64'))"/>
    </insert>
```

Hope it helps someone!